# Django 1.5 NoReverseMatch at /dashboard/projects/

Tags: python, django-1.5

I am using django 1.5 when i access http://example.com:8000/dashboard/projects/ i am getting error `NoReverseMatch at /dashboard/projects/ Reverse for 'project-details' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.`

#### dashboard/views.py

```
class ProjectlistView(ListView):
    """
    Project list page
    """
    template_name = 'projects.html'
    model = Project
    context_object_name = 'projects'
    paginate_by = 5

class ProjectDetailsView(DetailView):
    """
    Project details page
    """
    template_name = 'project-details.html'
    model = Project
```

#### dashboard/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',                       
    url(regex=r'^$', view=DashboardView.as_view(), name='index'),                       
    url(regex=r'projects/$', view=ProjectlistView.as_view(), name='projects'),
    url(regex=r'project/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', view=ProjectDetailsView.as_view(), name='project-details'),
)
```

#### my_project/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^dashboard/', include('frontend.urls', namespace='dashboard'),),
    url(r'admin/' ,include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

#### projects.html

```
{% url 'project-details' project.pk %}
```

Comment: Show us your CBV `ProjectDetailsView`?

Comment: And whole template `projects.html`?

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you use keyword syntax in projects.html? `{% url 'project-details' pk=project.pk %}`

Comment: @PauloAlmeida when i do like `{% url 'project-details' pk=project.pk %}` still same error, now my problem is solved i have added namespace like `{% url 'dashboard:project-details' project.pk %}`

Answer (score 2):

You defined your url patterns as using a named group, so you need to pass named arguments to the `url`tag, ie `{% url 'project-details' pk=project.pk %}`.

Also, you want to start your url patterns with a caret to make sure they dont match more than needed, ie: `^project/$` and `^project/(?P<pk>\d+)/$`.

Comment: i have added namespace in url, `{% url 'dashboard:project-details' project.pk %}`  and now it is working.